# Setting up basic jBPM project without external repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, jbpm

I'm trying to set up a very basic jBPM project. And when I say very basic, I mean the auto-setup project that you do in eclipse when you do File -> New -> Project -> jBPM project

Due to my companies strict firewall I am unable to use the jboss repository to fetch dependencies. i.e.

```
<repository>
  <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
  <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
  <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

So my question is.. what are the dependencies needed to get this template project running? I've thrown every dependency I could at this based off the imports and such, yet it still keeps failing during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

All the required jar files are available in community [download page](https://download.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.5.0.Final/jbpm-6.5.0.Final-bin.zip). You can include these jar files into classpath to run any jbpm project. Similar to this you can download drools library as well.